# Twitter's Future.collect not working concurrently (Scala)

Tags: scala, concurrency, twitter-util

Coming from a node.js background, I am new to Scala and I tried using Twitter's Future.collect to perform some simple concurrent operations. But my code shows sequential behavior rather than concurrent behavior. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code,

```
import com.twitter.util.Future

def waitForSeconds(seconds: Int, container:String): Future[String]  = Future[String] {
  Thread.sleep(seconds*1000)
  println(container + ": done waiting for " + seconds + " seconds")
  container + " :done waiting for " + seconds + " seconds"
}

def mainFunction:String = {
  val allTasks = Future.collect(Seq(waitForSeconds(1, "All"), waitForSeconds(3, "All"), waitForSeconds(2, "All")))
  val singleTask = waitForSeconds(1, "Single")

  allTasks onSuccess  { res =>
    println("All tasks succeeded with result " + res)
  }

  singleTask onSuccess { res =>
    println("Single task succeeded with result " + res)
  }

  "Function Complete"
}

println(mainFunction)
```

and this is the output I get,

```
All: done waiting for 1 seconds
All: done waiting for 3 seconds
All: done waiting for 2 seconds
Single: done waiting for 1 seconds
All tasks succeeded with result ArraySeq(All :done waiting for 1 seconds, All :done waiting for 3 seconds, All :done waiting for 2 seconds)
Single task succeeded with result Single :done waiting for 1 seconds
Function Complete
```

The output I expect is,

```
All: done waiting for 1 seconds
Single: done waiting for 1 seconds
All: done waiting for 2 seconds
All: done waiting for 3 seconds
All tasks succeeded with result ArraySeq(All :done waiting for 1 seconds, All :done waiting for 3 seconds, All :done waiting for 2 seconds)
Single task succeeded with result Single :done waiting for 1 seconds
Function Complete
```

Comment: Well the whole point of a `Future`, is offload the computation to another thread. So in the first line of your mainFunction, will spawn three new threads, which (when the spawned threads have finished) will spawn another thread to execute the oncomplete function. 
In the second line, another thread is spawned and will execute in parallel to the other threads. So I think the actual output seems valid...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twitter's futures are more explicit about where computations are executed than the Scala standard library futures. In particular, `Future.apply` will capture exceptions safely (like `s.c.Future`), but it doesn't say anything about which thread the computation will run in. In your case the computations are running in the main thread, which is why you're seeing the results you're seeing.

This approach has several advantages over the standard library's future API. For one thing it keeps method signatures simpler, since there's not an implicit `ExecutionContext` that has to be passed around everywhere. More importantly it makes it easier to avoid context switches ([here's a classic explanation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/finaglers/yWOr7-7CmPw/TBsJenqynQQJ) by Brian Degenhardt). In this respect Twitter's `Future` is more like Scalaz's `Task`, and has essentially the same performance benefits (described for example in [this blog post](http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2015/06/18/easy-performance-wins-with-scalaz/)).

The downside of being more explicit about where computations run is that you have to be more explicit about where computations run. In your case you could write something like this:

```
import com.twitter.util.{ Future, FuturePool }

val pool = FuturePool.unboundedPool

def waitForSeconds(seconds: Int, container:String): Future[String] = pool {
  Thread.sleep(seconds*1000)
  println(container + ": done waiting for " + seconds + " seconds")
  container + " :done waiting for " + seconds + " seconds"
}
```

This won't produce exactly the output you're asking for ("Function complete" will be printed first, and `allTasks` and `singleTask` aren't sequenced with respect to each other), but it will run the tasks in parallel on separate threads.

(As a footnote: the `FuturePool.unboundedPool` in my example above is an easy way to create a future pool for a demo, and is often just fine, but it isn't appropriate for CPU-intensive computations—see [the `FuturePool` API docs](http://twitter.github.io/util/docs/#com.twitter.util.FuturePool$) for other ways to create a future pool that will use an `ExecutorService` that you provide and can manage yourself.)

Comment: Excellent!

I used your code and also added a Thread.sleep(6000) to the last line and now I am seeing concurrent behaviour. The output after making the changes is,

`Function Complete`
`All: done waiting for 1 seconds`
`Single: done waiting for 1 seconds`
`Single task succeeded with result Single :done waiting for 1 seconds`
`All: done waiting for 2 seconds`
`All: done waiting for 3 seconds`
`All tasks succeeded with result ArraySeq(All :done waiting for 1 seconds, All :done waiting for 3 seconds, All :done waiting for 2 seconds)`

Comment: To add a little more. There is a recently-published doc on Twitter's futures that explains some design decisions behind them: https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/develop/doc/src/sphinx/developers/Futures.rst

Comment: (com.twitter.util.)Await.result(allTasks) may be better instead of Thread.sleep(6000)